# Relocation error when building GROMACS with MPICH

Tags: linux, gcc, mpi, mpich

I was trying to install a package, GROMACS, a molecular dynamics solver with mpich2 and got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libmpich.a(allreduce.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libmpich.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libgromacs_mpi.so.1.4.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/gromacs/CMakeFiles/libgromacs.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The interesting case is I installed mpich2 with `--enable-shared` flag and with `CXXFLAGS=-fPIC`.

Any idea how can it be solved???

Comment: was the dynamic lib (e.g. /usr/local/lib/libmpich.so) built ? unless GROMACS is directed to use the static version (e.g. libmpich.a) i think it should use the dynamic library by default. can you post the full command line that procuces the error ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet
it's a simple make command after cmake... the cmake was like this

`/root/cmake-3.9.1-Linux-x86_64/bin/cmake .. -DGMX_BUILD_OWN_FFTW=ON -DREGRESSIONTEST_DOWNLOAD=ON -DGMX_MPI=ON -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/gromacs-5.1.4`

Comment: do you have the link command instead ? if you run `make V=1` you will likely get that at the end of the logs

Comment: Let me recover that...

Comment: This is what I'm getting after `make V=1` :
`make[2]: *** No rule to make target ``/usr/local/lib/libmpich.a', needed by ``lib/libgromacs_mpi.so.1.4.0'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [src/gromacs/CMakeFiles/libgromacs.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Comment: well, obviously, something has changed between your initial post and your latest message. `/usr/local/lib/libmpich.a` used to be here, but it is no more here. if you rebuilt mpich, you have to run `cmake` again, and then you can run `make`